# Prove composition of two surjections is surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ are both surjections.

Since $f$ is surjective, then for every $b \in B$ there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a)= b$.  Since $g$ is surjective, for every $c \in C$, there's  $b \in B$ such that $g(b) = c$. Then $g(f(a)) = g(b) = c$.

Would this work?

edit; I didn't realize there are similar questions on this site. Don't mind if this post is deleted.

Comment: [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Composite_of_Surjections_is_Surjection).

Comment: Just to make it clearer I would state what it would mean for the composition to be surjective, i.e. for every $c\in C$ there exists an $a\in A$ such that $f(c)=a$. You can also try it by contradiction which might come a little faster.

Comment: Very close.  But start with the c, state there is a g(b) = c.  Then state for the g(b) there is an a such that f(a) = b.  So for c there exists an a such that g(f(a)) = g(b) = c.  The way you wrote it there's no guarantee that the b you derived from c is that same b that you picked from random to derive a.  Do you see the difference?  From c we get b; from b we get a.  But you wrote.  From b we get a; and from c we get a b' which may be a different number than the b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds ok, but i would recommend switching the first and the second sentence:

Since $g$ is surjective, for every $c \in C$, there's  $b \in B$ such that $g(b) = c$.
Since $f$ is surjective, then for **this** $b \in B$ there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a)= b$.
 Then $g(f(a)) = g(b) = c$.

Comment: You pretty much have to switch the sentences.  The b in the first sentence was aribitrary.  The b is the second is $g^{-1}(c)$ and may be an entirely different number.

Comment: @ fleablood, are you agreeing with @ supinf or are you actually saying they need to fix their post? Because I fixed the entry in my notebook exactly as they showed.